# dyld`gdb_image_notifier exception when i run my application in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, ios8, xcode5

When try to load my application on device sometimes i got following
exception

**dyld`gdb_image_notifier:0x2beca0cc:  bx     lr**

but after stop and run again everything works fine, can anyone tell me why this occurs

Comment: XCode is full of these. We just feel lucky if we find a solution. If not ignore and hope it does not affect the app when it is on the market.

Answer (score 5):

Basically it seems there is a breakpoint in the debugger. Thought it's not a solution, in order to run the app on the device, just click "Debug" and then "Continue" (or ^⌘Y). That should help pass the breakpoint and carry on running the app.
"Debug" -> "Deactivate Breakpoints" can help too in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

**Product -> Clean** ...fixed it for me.

Comment: Unbelievable. Xcode 8.2 throwing this exception when loading a keyboard extension.

Comment: @DanLoughney, I am facing a similar issue for Keyboard extension. Have you resolved it?

Comment: After working with this a couple months I just need to call it fussy. Tons of time built into Xcode to build apps on iOS/macOS but no similar effort put into app extensions. It works or it doesn't. No way to know when, why, or how. Do clean cmd-shift-k and alt-cmd-shift-k when it happens. Also this is a **must** when changing from simulator to real device.

Answer (score 1):

I Think the problem is within `GLKit Framework`.

So Try this out, make `GLKit Framework` optional in the path given below in the image and than build again.

The framework was being pulled into the build under

`Project->BuildPhases->LinkBinaryWithLibraries.`

[image]

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I too just started getting this breakpoint while running on an iPhone4 v 7.1.2. I'm not linking with GLKit.framework so this suggestion didn't help. I have had some success cleaning the library and reinstalling. After that it seems to be intermittent. Running outside the debugger works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I face same problem and not found any answer.
After some hours I find this cause by conflict constraints in autolayout story board.
And this exception no longer occur after I fix all conflict constraints