# dyld`gdb_image_notifier exception when i run my application in device OS 9 WORK fine in OS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

When I try to load my application on device sometimes I got following exception:

> dyld`gdb_image_notifier:0x2beca0cc: bx lr

but after stop and run again everything works fine, can anyone tell me why this occurs?

Comment: I am also facing same issue in xCode 6.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld\`gdb\_image\_notifier exception when i run my application in device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758465/dyldgdb-image-notifier-exception-when-i-run-my-application-in-device)